# Form validation with Javascript - Field value must be between 2 specific numbers

Tags: javascript, forms, numbers, background-color

I have a form on a page. On the form there is a field named Birthyear. I need to figure out the following in javascript:

When a value between 1900-2012 is entered into the field, the form are accepted. If value is not between 1900-2012, the Birthyear text box background color turn yellow.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

My HTML is as follow:

```
</head><body>

<div id="div1">
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Username:   <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br>         
Birth Year: <input type="text" id="birthYear" name="birthYear"><br><br>
<input type="submit"  value="Submit">
</form>

</div>

<div id="div2">
<img src="cat.jpg"    id="im1" name="image1"/>
<img src="dog.jpg"    id="im2" name="image2"/>
<img src="fish.jpg"   id="im3" name="image3" class='double'/>
</div>


</body></html>
```

My JS is as follow:

```
document.getElementById("username").focus();
function validateForm(){
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["username"].value;

if (x==""){
alert("Username Required!");
document.getElementById("username").focus();
}


var dob = document.forms["myForm"]["birthYear"];
var y = dob.value;


if(isNaN(dob)){
    alert('must be a number');
    dob.select();
    return false;

}

}
```

Comment: Use `parseInt(y)` to get the value of the year, then check if it's between 1900 and 2012.

Comment: btw you have mistake, it is isNaN(y) and not dob. Dob is dom element.

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateForm(){
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["username"].value;

if (x==""){
alert("Username Required!");
document.getElementById("username").focus();
}


var dob = document.forms["myForm"]["birthYear"];
var y = dob.value;

if(!isNaN(y)){

if(y>=1900 && y<=2012) {
    //Correct
 } else {
     //Wrong
     document.getElementById("birthYear").style.background= "yellow";
     document.getElementById("birthYear").focus();
     return false;
 }
} else {
  alert('must be a number');
}
}
```

Comment: you should move if else with y outside of isNaN if because if user enter any numeric value additional check will not be done.

Comment: Hi there,thank you so much for your help. The code makes sense, but for some reason it still doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: @user2147761 Sorry, i forgot to add not operator "!" in isNaN() condition. Now the example works. Thanks for pointing it out.