# Javascript Form Validation Between 2 Numbers

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I need a form field that if a number under 21 and over 35 is entered there is a pop up up that tells them to enter a number between 21 and 35.

Firstly I have seen this one, it doesn't solve my requirements:

[Form validation with Javascript - Field value must be between 2 specific numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541827/form-validation-with-javascript-field-value-must-be-between-2-specific-numbers)

I have the following and it doesn't work, any idea why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm() {
var x = document.forms["daysCalc"]["days"].value;
if (x>=21 && x<=35) {
    alert("Number must be between 21 and 35");
    return false;
}
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="daysCalc" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Days: <input type="text" name="days">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Your help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Because your logic is exactly the wrong way around. You're showing the error message and return false when the number *is* between 21 and 35.

Comment: Can't believe I did that! Must be to early :| Thank you for spotting it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually sending the error message when the user is entering a number within the given range, not outside the given range.

Try this:

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["daysCalc"]["days"].value;
    if (x < 21 || x > 35) {
        alert("Number must be between 21 and 35");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["daysCalc"]["days"].value;
    if (x<=20 || x>=36) {
        alert("Number must be between 21 and 35");
        return false;

}
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="daysCalc" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Days: <input type="text" name="days">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```